# VBA: I get the following error: run-time error '1004' Application-defined or object-defined error

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error

**Current issue:**

My code used to work partially until I add extra data to sheet2, now when it fails and debug sends me to:

```
Set partsheet = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1", Range("A65536").End(xlUp))
```

**Utility of this code:**

I basically have two columns in different sheets: that I want to compare & when similar import data:

Sheet1 - column1 is a job number

Sheet1 - column2 is a part number

for the same job number you can have multiple parts - meaning the job number repeats itself in column1

Sheet2 - column1 is the same job numbers as sheet1 but the data is never repeat

Sheet2 - column2 is an id number specific to each job number (hence why in this case job numbers do not repeat themselves)

Therefore I want to import the data from Sheet2 - column2 using the commun job numbers as reference point. When I import the data to Sheet1 - column3 the unique id number will have to repeat itself for job numbers in column1(sheet1) that are repeated - hence the double for loop.

**What I mean by used to partially work:**

To start with the code only partially worked, I think this was due to the fact that certain job numbers in sheet1 - column1 have no corresponding value in sheet2 - column1 (the data isnt perfect). Maybe I need to add code for the else part of the if statement but im not sure what.

**vba Code:**

```
Option Explicit

Sub testFil()
    Dim Jobref_in_partsheet As Range
    Dim Jobref_in_jobsheet As Range
    Dim partsheet As Range
    Dim jobsheet As Range
    Dim MyRow As Long
    Dim MyOtherRow As Long

    Set partsheet = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1", Range("A65536").End(xlUp))
    Set jobsheet  = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1", Range("A65536").End(xlUp))

    For Each Jobref_in_partsheet In partsheet
        For Each Jobref_in_jobsheet In jobsheet
            If Jobref_in_partsheet.Value = Jobref_in_jobsheet.Value Then
                MyRow = Jobref_in_partsheet.Row
                MyOtherRow = Jobref_in_jobsheet.Row
                Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(MyRow, 3) = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(MyOtherRow, 2)
            Else
                 'Do nothing
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

I'd really appreciate any help I could get.

Comment: You should be able to edit the original post to reflect these changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1", Range("A65536").End(xlUp))
```

There is a problem here: you are trying to create a `Range` object, first cell of which is `A1` of the `Sheet1`, and last cell is the last cell used in column `A` in the active sheet. As you can guess, `Sheet1` and active sheet can be different sheets, and you can't create a range that belongs multiple sheets.

You should provide the parent sheet explicitly for your last cell:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1", Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A65536").End(xlUp))
```

[Using `.Address`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13975716/11683) is not really a workaround, as it might result in address fetched from one sheet to be used against another sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Answer Update:

I think this might be more easily accomplished using =VLOOKUP, which is just a normal excel function.  Basically you'll want to apply this formula to every cell in Sheet1 row C.

```
'Psudeo Code
=VLOOKUP([look up value] A1, [range to look in] Sheet2!A:B, [row to return] 2, [use exact match] false)
```

You'll need to read up on VLOOKUP before using it, but hopefully my little bit of psuedo code can show you if you can actually use it for your purpose.  If you implement it like I said then basically it will use the first value (A1) to look up something in another range (the first column of A:B).  If it finds a match it will return what is in the second column (hence the 2, so column B of A:B).  False is just to tell the program that you do not want matches that are similar, you only want matches that are exactly the same.

Yeah, VLOOKUP is confusing as all get out, but it's quite useful.

This will be a lot easier than using VBA to do the same task.  I suppose that may or may not actually answer your question, but I thought I'd bring it up just incase you hadn't considered it.

Old, wrong, answer:

I tend to make sure I turn everything to strings when creating a range.  EG:

```
Set partsheet = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1:" & Range("B65536").End(xlUp).Address)
```

Range("B65536").End(xlUp).Address will return the string representing the address of the top of that column.  IF, for example, the top was "B31" then "B1:" & Range("B65536").End(xlUp).Address should return "B1:B31" as the range.

Comment: Cheers Doug, the .Address to turn into string worked perfectly with the code I had :) Ill still have a read up on VLOOKUP. Thanks again.

Comment: Glad to help :-).  If my answer was the correct one it would be good if you accepted it as your answer...