# Direct reference to range Excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, select, reference

I'm having trouble using a direct reference. I'm trying to put values in the root workbook without using select or activate. But my code gives an error if the sheet to where the data needs to be copied isn't active. If the sheet is active the code works fine...

Here is my code

```
Workbooks(root).Activate
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Application.Workbooks(root)

wb.Sheets("d_eff_stress").Cells(1, n).Value = filename
wb.Sheets("d_eff_stress").Range(Cells(3, n), Cells(100, n)).Value = varray1
wb.Sheets("eff_stress").Cells(1, n).Value = filename
wb.Sheets("eff_stress").Range(Cells(3, n), Cells(100, n)).Value = varray2
```

The solution: full reference to the range... I could have known

```
Workbooks(root).Activate
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Application.Workbooks(root)

wb.Sheets("d_eff_stress").Cells(1, n).Value = filename
wb.Sheets("d_eff_stress").Range(wb.Sheets("d_eff_stress").Cells(3, n), wb.Sheets("d_eff_stress").Cells(100, n)).Value = varray1
wb.Sheets("eff_stress").Cells(1, n).Value = filename
wb.Sheets("eff_stress").Range(wb.Sheets("eff_stress").Cells(3, n), wb.Sheets("eff_stress").Cells(100, n)).Value = varray2
```

Comment: Check `root` holds the correct book.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBA: I get the following error: run-time error '1004' Application-defined or object-defined error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13975496/vba-i-get-the-following-error-run-time-error-1004-application-defined-or-obj)

Comment: Don't put the solution in the question as it makes the answers seem unneeded.  You mark the correct answer by clicking on the grey green check mark by the answer.  But yo have to wait for 15 minutes from the time the question was asked.  So come back in a few minutes and mark the answer as correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to assign the sheet parentage to the `Cells` inside the range:

```
wb.Sheets("d_eff_stress").Range(wb.Sheets("d_eff_stress").Cells(3, n), wb.Sheets("d_eff_stress").Cells(100, n)).Value
```

To do less typing use `With` Blocks:

```
Workbooks(root).Activate
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Application.Workbooks(root)

With wb.Sheets("d_eff_stress")
    .Cells(1, n).Value = filename
    .Range(.Cells(3, n), .Cells(100, n)).Value = varray1
End With

With wb.Sheets("eff_stress")
    .Cells(1, n).Value = filename
    .Range(.Cells(3, n), .Cells(100, n)).Value = varray2
End With
```